# Do zombie processes still occupy an entry in the parent's children-list?

Tags: linux-kernel, children, zombie-process

I'm currently working on a module of linux kernel for univeristy.
As part of the assignment I have to iterate over all the children of the current processes (to check the value of a custom field I added) , using the children list in it's task_struct.

Are zombie process's still on that list? If yes, can I somehow ignore them while iterating?

Thank you

Comment: This should be very easy to test, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the task_struct's item `state`

```
struct task_struct {
    u64 curr_chain_key;
    int lockdep_depth;
    unsigned int lockdep_recursion;
    struct held_lock held_locks[MAX_LOCK_DEPTH];
    gfp_t lockdep_reclaim_gfp;
    int pid;
    int state;
    char comm[17];
};
```